# Org capture into org table

Tags: org-mode, org-table, org-capture

Normally `org-capture` lets one insert a templated subtree somewhere into an existing Org file or tree node.

Is it possible to use `org-capture` to instead add a row to an existing Org-mode table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is.  For example, with this org file:

```
* my table
| blah  | blah |
```

And this elisp:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-capture-templates
   (quote
    (("t" "Table" table-line
      (file+headline "" "my table")
      "|%?| Blah |")))))
```

I can run `org-capture` and it appends a line to the table.

If it doesn't find your org file, you may need to replace the `""` in the `file+headline` form with a file path (I don't remember what the `""` defaults to, but it finds my main org-mode file).